# FluentValidation not working on form submit when JavaScript is disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, fluentvalidation

I'm using [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) to validate models. I've set it up as follows:

### Model

```
public class UserViewModel {
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public String FullName { get; set; }
    public String CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

### Validation Class

```
public class UserViewModelValidation: AbstractValidator<UserViewModel> {
    public UserViewModelValidation() {
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotNull().WithLocalizedMessage(() => ValidationResources.EmailRequired);
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress().WithLocalizedMessage(() => ValidationResources.EmailValid);
        RuleFor(x => x.PhoneNumber).NotNull().WithLocalizedMessage(() => ValidationResources.PhoneNumberRequired);
        RuleFor(x => x.FullName).NotNull().WithLocalizedMessage(() => ValidationResources.FullNameRequired);
        RuleFor(x => x.CompanyName).NotNull().WithLocalizedMessage(() => ValidationResources.CompanyNameRequired);
    }
}
```

### Registration in Global.asax

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
```

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateUser(UserViewModel vm) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(vm);

    var service = DiConfig.Resolve<IUserService>();
    service.Update(vm);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

### View

```
<form action="@Url.Action("UpdateUser", "User")">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-input">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, FormResources.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        <div class="error-message">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, FormResources.PhoneNumber)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
        <div class="error-message">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FullName, FormResources.FullName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName)
        <div class="error-message">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FullName)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyName, FormResources.CompanyName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyName)
        <div class="error-message">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CompanyName)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
        <input type="submit" value="@FormResources.UpdateButton">
    </div>
</form>
```

### Problem

Client side validation works perfectly. No issue here. However, I've tried to make sure that the validation will work even when the JS is disabled on the browser. What I've expected was to see the error messages after page reload when I submit the form, without client side validations.

However, the result is - no validation messages at all, but only `query string params` in the URL with submitted values.

### Question

How can I make validation work when JavaScript disabled? What I need is (when validation fails) showing the validation messages after the post and page reload.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing the part where you tell MVC to run the validator for a particular class. [According to the docs](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation), you can do it either by decorating the model class:

```
[Validator(typeof(UserViewModelValidation))]
public class UserViewModel {
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public String FullName { get; set; }
    public String CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

... or by configuring a ValidatorFactory:

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(provider => {
  provider.ValidatorFactory = new MyCustomValidatorFactory();
});
```